Does integrability of $f>0$ imply integrability of $\ln (f)$?
In problem 36, chapter 18 of Spivak's Calculus, he asks the following:

Prove that for all integrable $f>0$, we have $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \ln f \le \ln \left(\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f \right)$$

I am able to prove this provided I assume $\ln f$ is also integrable on $[a,b].$ Is this a  mistake by the author or does the integrability of $f>0$ actually imply integrability of $\ln f$?

$\ln f$ need not be ((properly) Riemann) integrable, for example if the infimum of $f$ is $0$. But if the infimum is strictly positive, then yes you get a ((properly) Riemann) integrable function.

$\log(f)$ need not be integrable, but the integrability of $f$ and convexity of $t\mapsto -\log t$ implies that $(-\log\circ f)_+$ is integrable and so $\int \log\circ f$ is well defined as an extended real number possibly taking value $-\infty$. See here.

You may consider $\log (f+{1\over n}).$ These functions are Riemann integrable as compositions of integrable functions with a continuous function. Then także the limit when $n\to\infty.$

@RyszardSzwarc I am sorry but I don't follow. If compositions of integrable functions with continuous functions are integrable, wouldn't that automatically imply $\ln(f)$ itself is integrable? What is the role of $\frac1n$ here?

If $g$ is continuous on $[m,M]$ where $m=\inf f$ and $M=\sup f$ then if $f$' is Riemann integrable do is $g\circ f.$ If $m=0$ then $g(y)=\ln y$ is not continuous, even not well defined on $[0,M].$  Adding $1/n$ gives $\inf f\ge 1/n.$ So $\ln (f+1/n)$ is Riemann integrable.
